# If we have a planar graph, why is it true that there always exists a vertex such that $deg(v) \leq 3$ or a face $f$ such that $deg(f) \leq 3$?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

If we consider $G$ to be a planar graph with no loops or multiple edges, there exists a vertex $v \in V(G)$ such that $deg(v) \leq 3$ or there exists a face that $deg(f) \leq 3$.

I'm not entirely sure why this is true, I have drawn out a few examples and can see it that way but beyond that quite unsure.

Comment: Use Euler's formula and the handshake lemma.

Comment: Thank you I will give that a shot

Comment: So using the handshaking lemma and assuming every vertex has a degree greater than 3 and that every face has a degree greater than 3 we get the following inequalities:

$2m>3f$ & $2m > 3n$

Substituting this into euler's formula we get:
$n-m+f < \frac{2m}{3} - m + \frac{2m}{3}$
which simplifies to $n-m+f < \frac{m}{3}$

I'm kind of stuck here unsure how to proceed to prove this using a contradiction @MishaLavrov

Comment: You can find the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1330749/1096797), since a planar graph with face degree at least 4 is triangle-free.

Comment: Well, it looks like the question has already been asked, but to explain what went wrong with your attempt: when working with integers, using a non-strict inequality like $\ge 4$ instead of a strict one like $>3$ will give you much better results.